# Displaying a dataset that is an object of a class in R

Tags: r, dataset

I am trying to implement the TSP package. I need to understand the input data structure so I can input my data. But apparently I am not able to display it.

The introduction paper ( [link](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/TSP/vignettes/TSP.pdf) ) describes how to run the algorithm on a data set *USCA50* that comes with the TSP package. I attempted to display the dataset using the lines of code below:

```
library("TSP")
data("USCA50")
USCA50

#to run the solver 
solve_TSP(USCA50)
```

It produces the output below but does not display the data set.

```
object of class ‘TSP’ 
50 cities (distance ‘euclidean’)
```

I am trying to understand dataset/input so I can run my own data/input with the solve_TSP() function.

Comment: try `head(USCA50)` and `str(USCA50)`. Also read `?head`, `?str`

Comment: *head()* function gives me an array of non-coordinate looking numbers. For a TSP, I  really expected a dataframe with city names and coordinates. And I am not able to interpret the *str()* results.

Comment: read `?USCA50`. The dataset gives distance between the cities. Reading that documentation will give you more information

Comment: Ok. So its *like* a matrix of distances and doesn't require coordinates. I tried to imitate that; mocked a matrix(1:20,4) as an input but it did not work. Says ** no applicable method for 'solve_TSP'**. So its structure must be different than a regular matrix and still a mystery to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a nutshell:

```
class(USCA50)
```

Shows that the input is an object of the following classes: TSP, dist.

So any input must be fist a distance matrix. And that can be construct using `dist()` by inputting locations and coordinates. Secondly, use TSP() constructor.

```
distance_matrix <- dist(coordinates)
tsp <- TSP(distance_matrix)
solve_TSP(tsp)
```

Answer (score 3):

To see it as a matrix:

```
as.matrix(USCA50)
```

If you just want to have a look at what it contains, I suggest you `Hmisc::describe`